# How to update a property of an object/entity when a button click occurs in Springboot & React

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, hibernate, intellij-idea

I'm facing a problem which I cannot seem to resolve.

I have an entity which has a property (specifically a string) with a value of 'In magazijn':

```
package com.Code.Pakket.management.model;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

//Men maakt een JPA entity class zodat hibernate met onze data kan werken.
@Entity
public class Pakketje {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private int code;
    private String status ="In magazijn";

    public Pakketje() {
    }
```

I would like this string to change when a button click occurs in the react application. The specific object from which the value should be changed is already existing inside of the database, and only the value "In magazijn" should be changed to "Onderweg". This value should change inside of the database.

I have tried the following inside of the service class:

```
    @Override
    public String StatusOnderweg(Pakketje pakketje) {
        return pakketjeRepository.save(pakketje.setStatus("Onderweg"));
    }
```

So "Pakketje pakketje" is the object of which the string should be changed. I thought about saving the specific object once more to the database (even tough the object already exists) and save it with another string.

My Repository:

```
package com.Code.Pakket.management.repository;

import com.Code.Pakket.management.model.Pakketje;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

//https://www.javadevjournal.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-with-hibernate/ -- Punt5.
@Repository
public interface PakketjeRepository extends JpaRepository<Pakketje,Integer> {
}
```

I just don't have an idea how to make this code with a repository, service and controller structure... Any advice?

Thanks in advance.